# How to do multi OS level access of a file using pathlib module?

Tags: python

So here I am writing a python program that read a text file and print its content. So I want to make a system that I write a txt file using a python script in window and then read it using another python script in linux. I will transfer the text file using google cloud. How can I use pathlib module to handle the path of the file in either of the OS.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: When I made the python file to write in the text file I got the text file in the same directory so I just had to give the name of the file as :   f=open('abc.txt', 'w ')

Comment: I don't understand what does the fil_Path= pathlib.Path('abc.txt') does.